# Foreach loop in XML into SQL table

Tags: sql, xml, powershell

Hi I am relatively new to both PowerShell and XML, I am trying to create a loop that goes though the whole XML document copy it into my SQL sever database. Currently in PowerShell I can only copy the OrderInfo into the database. I would like to get the table to display both the ShopDetails and the OrderInfo on the same line in the table. Please see my XML below

```
<OrderBatch>
  <ShopDetails>
        <ShopName>ShopALot</ShopName>
        <depoNumberID>121</depoNumberID>
        <totalOrderID>2424</totalOrderID>
        <AmountOfOrdersToday>2</AmountOfOrdersToday>
  </ShopDetails>
  <OrderInfo>
        <OrderID>1</OrderID>
        <ItemsInTheOrder>3</ItemsInTheOrder>
        <OrderDate>05/08/2017</OrderDate>
        <depoPostCode>N4 5TS</depoPostCode>
  </OrderInfo>
  <OrderInfo>
        <OrderID>2</OrderID>
        <ItemsInTheOrder>1</ItemsInTheOrder>
        <OrderDate>05/08/2017</OrderDate>
        <depoPostCode>N4 5TS</depoPostCode>
  </OrderInfo>
```

Comment: Your table has no primary key?

Comment: OrderID is my primary key

Comment: Can you show the code that isn't working?

Comment: Why can you only copy the OrderInfo? "*I would like to get the table*" - what table? What do you mean you want the table to "display" something? guess this is a homework problem for a database course, and you're designing a database layout for it? If so I'd expect to see a table for Shops, (maybe Depos with depoPostCode belonging to it), one for Orders for joining orders<->shops .. because your everything-in-one-row doesn't sound workable. Anyway it's not clear what you're trying to do, what you can't do and need help with, or what design you're working with